# Help please recovering a wallet from a 17 word mnemonic phrase and other info

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

4 years ago I bought bitcoin and I have 
a 17 word mnemonic phrase
an identifier
a bitcoin address
and what I believe is a password

Does anyone know how I can access this bitcoin?

Comment: You can verify that it is in fact the blockchain.info wallet by seeing if all your words are on their wordlist: https://gist.github.com/fulldecent/fa6a223ab4adb7672bba4a6653cd1b0e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you remember where you created the wallet?
I assume it was a legacy wallet on blockchain.info, if so you can recover your ID and password here https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password .

Comment: ah ha...by George I think that's it.  I couldn't log in using my pc so I tried using my tablet and got in.  thank you for the assist